# Custom Subject not getting displayed - {{subject}}

Tags: java, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm sending a email request thru standalone java program. But, when the email is delivered the subject is displayed as (no subject).

I've created an account
Created a dynamic template
Selected a blank Template
Wanted to pass custom values thru JAVA code
At the sendgrid template side I've configured like the below mentioned
{{subject}}
and
{{#each content}}

{{this.type}}
{{this.value}}

{{/each}}

When I preview it with the test data section (pasted json created from standalone java), it is showing correct values.
But when I execute the standalone program , the subject and other content part does not get displayed.

Java Code

```
import com.sendgrid.Method;
import com.sendgrid.Request;
import com.sendgrid.Response;
import com.sendgrid.SendGrid;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.Mail;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Content;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Email;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Personalization;

import java.io.IOException;


public class WithMailHelper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Email from = new Email("xxxx@xyz.com");
        Email to = new Email("abcdef@gmail.com");
        Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

        mail.setTemplateId("d-abcdefghijk");
        mail.setSubject("test version of twilio");
        
        mail.addContent(new Content("text/html", "<strong>sendGrid is easy to do anywhere, even with Java</strong>"));

        final Personalization personalization1 = new Personalization();
        personalization1.addTo(new Email("abc@xyz.com", "ABCDEF GHIJK"));
        personalization1.addDynamicTemplateData("name", "ABC");
        personalization1.addDynamicTemplateData("city", "XYZ");
        personalization1.setSubject("testing subject thru personalization");
        mail.addPersonalization(personalization1);

        SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("SG.KEYVALUEPAIRAPI);
        Request request = new Request();
        try {
            request.setMethod(Method.POST);
            request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
            System.out.println(mail.build());
            request.setBody(mail.build());
            Response response = sg.api(request);
            System.out.println("status code: " + response.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("response body: " + response.getBody());
            System.out.println("response header : " + response.getHeaders());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("inside exception" + ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

email with custom subject and content should have displayed. but it is not

Comment: I'm guessing what the issue could be based on experience working with this. Could you add an extra dynamic template data with key `subject` and the subject you want?
I think when you're using `{{subject}}` or `{{any_field}}` inside your subject field, it will pull that data from the dynamic template data, not from the subject field itself.

Comment: @Swimburger - I deleted the Personalization section and tested. Hoping it would pick up from  mail.setSubject("test version of twilio"); But did not work

Comment: @Swimburger - When I test the email thru 1) Preview with Test data - it works fine.  2) Send a test email from sendgrid site - it works fine. Problem occurs only when running thru standalone java.

Comment: When using Dynamic Templates, the subject configured on the template is used, and the subject set using `setSubject` is ignored I think. 
Don't delete the Personalization section, use the personalization and add another dynamic template data item, with key `subject` and the subject value you want it to have.

Comment: @Swimburger - ok got your point. Scenario what I'm trying to test is --> I want to add order id in the subject. How do I implement this?

Comment: Two ways you could do it, update your subject in the Dynamic Template in the SendGrid app to "Foo Bar {{order_id}}", and then add a dynamic template data with key `order_id` and the order ID value.
Alternatively, keep the subject in the Dynamic Template as "{{subject}}", and then add a dynamic template data with key `subject` and the value "Foo Bar " + order ID.
Did you try to see if the template data gets embedded into the subject tho?

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: @Swimburger - The substitution of handlebars is not working currently. But When I test with test data section with the output from mail.build(). There it works

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going back and forth in the comments, I verified your problem and the solution, so here is a more detailed explanation.

I copied your code and removed the bits that are irrelevant for your usecase.
Since you're using Dynamic Email Templates and persionalizations, I removed the following:

- I removed `To` from the `Mail` since it'll be provided by the personalization
- I removed the plain text and HTML content, since the content will be provided by the Dynamic Email Template.
- I removed the `Subject` from the `Mail` and `Personalization` since it'll be provided by the Dynamics Email Template.

This is what the code looks like now:

```java
package org.example;

import com.sendgrid.Method;
import com.sendgrid.Request;
import com.sendgrid.Response;
import com.sendgrid.SendGrid;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.Mail;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Email;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Personalization;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Mail mail = new Mail();
            mail.setFrom(new Email("[SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS]", "[SENDER_NAME]"));
            mail.setTemplateId("d-[YOUR_DYNAMIC_TEMPLATE_ID]");

            final Personalization personalization1 = new Personalization();
            personalization1.addTo(new Email("[RECIPIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS]", "[RECIPIENT_NAME]"));
            personalization1.addDynamicTemplateData("car_name", "Volkswagen Beetle");
            mail.addPersonalization(personalization1);

            SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("SG.[YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY}");
            Request request = new Request();
            request.setMethod(Method.POST);
            request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
            System.out.println(mail.build());
            request.setBody(mail.build());
            Response response = sg.api(request);
            System.out.println("status code: " + response.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("response body: " + response.getBody());
            System.out.println("response header : " + response.getHeaders());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("inside exception" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I added the `car_name` Dynamic Template Data, so I can use it in the email subject of the Dynamic Email Template, [following this guidance](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260802535110-Create-a-Dynamic-Email-Subject-Line-with-Mustache-Templates).

[image: Settings of a SendGrid Dynamic Email Template with subject that uses template data.]

When I do set the subject using `mail.SetSubject` or `personalization1.setSubject`, those subjects are ignored, and the subject configured on the Dynamic Email Template is still used. Even when the subject configured on the Dynamic Email Template is empty, the `mail.subject` and `personalization.subject` are still ignored. When you're using Dynamic Email Templates, it has to be set using the subject on the Dynamic Email Template.

One workaround is to set the subject on the Dynamic Email Template to `{{subject}}` and set a dynamic template data with key `subject` and whatever subject you like:

```java
personalization1.addDynamicTemplateData("subject", "Your Volkswagen Beetle Extended Car Warranty");
```

[image: SendGrid Dynamic Email Template settings where subject is set to {{subject}}]

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. It worked !!. very well articulated response. The thing is when we implement using dynamic template --> we have pass key-value in personalization1.addDynamicTemplateData object :) (yes)

Comment: It was a little hard to explain in the comments, especially because there's a lot of ambiguity going on here. I'm glad I could help! Please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Since i'm a newbie, I do not have the reputation to upvote the answer